# User service is not running after the rebooting

Tags: linux, services, oracle-linux

I have created a service xvfb and copied it under directory **/usr/lib/systemd/system/**
also I have created another **xvfb.serive** which internally start/stop my **xvfb** service.
I want my service to start automatically after the reboot.
But some how after the reboot I am not able to see the Xvfb process using `ps -ef | grep Xvfb`.
Could anyone please help me with this. Currently I am using Oracle Linux Server release 7.9 linux.

[image]

**xvfb.service**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you enable the service (`systemctl enable xvfb`)? What does `systemctl is-enabled xvfb.service` say?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: systemctl is-enabled xvfb.service is showing enabled @Wieland